# (discord.py) running multiple bots at once

Tags: ubuntu-server, discord.py

I'm using a Linux server to host an assortment of bots at once, and I would like to know if it's possible to run multiple bots through the same shell at one time, they're all using the same script bar 3 those 3 can be executed in the same script as the other bots. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can install screen on your server and run the bots in different screens. You can always create new screens and detach from them without making the script close. I use screen myself to run different bots on my CentOs server. You can also check [this link](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) for more info.